# Wireless mouse not working on Raspberry pi zero w

Tags: mouse

Am having Raspberry pi zero w and Raspberry pi 3.

Wireless mouse is working fine with model 3 but not with Zero W.

Any solution to make it work with Zero W?

Comment: It works on RPi 3 because you had paired it with RPi3... You post provide no information on what you have try...

Comment: have added "usbhid.mousepoll=0" in /boot/cmdline.txt